# Chrome double page request

Tags: html, google-chrome, manifest, html5-appcache

Given the page:

```
**Page 1**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="offline.appcache">
    <body></body>
</html>
```

And given the alternative page with no reference to the appcache:

```
**Page 2**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Where the appcache file makes no reference at all to the HTML page is it referenced from.

**In Chrome**

- Page 1 is requested twice.
- Page 2 is requested once.

The double request does not show in the developer tools for Chrome, it is a silent double load.

**In IE/Firefox**

- Both pages are requested once

This is problematic because on the page load event we have server side code that logs the page view.  This creates two records, not one which results in garbage statistics.

Does anyone have a good work-around to stop the double page load, or at least recognise when it has happened?

Comment: if (Chrome) pageCount--? :)